# Find Origin that passed Core Web Vitals Stat?

Tags: chrome-ux-report

The changelog (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report/bigquery/changelog)reports the origins having good Core Web Vitals, and This info is excellent!  Please share if you know the below information related to good Core Web Vitals Stat.

1. Is changelog reporting for Desktop Or Mobile Or Tablet OR all three?
2. Was it for the entire Origin Or only for the homepage of Origin?
3. Where can I see the list of origins that passed Core Web Vitals?  If not available & need to find ourself would you mind Giving the query Or Add into Crux CookBook (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/CrUX/tree/master/sql)?  I tried to run myself constructing query & run, Got Quote Exceed error sounds due to account limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Also answered in the [CrUX discussion forum](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chrome-ux-report/c/glcBP606Wmg/m/8qgfRSe_AAAJ), but for anyone who found this question on SO first, I'll reshare my response.

> 1. Is changelog reporting for Desktop Or Mobile Or Tablet OR all three?

All three combined.

> 2. Was it for the entire Origin Or only for the homepage of Origin?

All BigQuery data is aggregated at the origin level, so these compliance rates apply to the entire origin.

> 3. Where can I see the list of origins that passed Core Web Vitals?  If not available & need to find ourself would you mind Giving the query Or Add into Crux CookBook (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/CrUX/tree/master/sql)?  I tried to run myself constructing query & run, Got Quote Exceed error sounds due to account limitation.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/CrUX/blob/main/sql/core-web-vitals-compliance-rates.sql is a good starting point. Here's a modification of that query to get the list of origins that pass the CWV assessment: (793 MB processed)

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION IS_GOOD (good FLOAT64, needs_improvement FLOAT64, poor FLOAT64) RETURNS BOOL AS (
  good / (good + needs_improvement + poor) >= 0.75
);

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION IS_NON_ZERO (good FLOAT64, needs_improvement FLOAT64, poor FLOAT64) RETURNS BOOL AS (
  good + needs_improvement + poor > 0
);


SELECT DISTINCT
  origin
FROM
  `chrome-ux-report.materialized.metrics_summary`
WHERE
  date = '2021-03-01' AND
  IS_GOOD(fast_lcp, avg_lcp, slow_lcp) AND
  IS_GOOD(fast_fid, avg_fid, slow_fid) AND
  IS_GOOD(small_cls, medium_cls, large_cls) AND
  IS_NON_ZERO(fast_lcp, avg_lcp, slow_lcp) AND
  IS_NON_ZERO(fast_fid, avg_fid, slow_fid) AND
  IS_NON_ZERO(small_cls, medium_cls, large_cls)
```